# For loop monthly budget program creating error

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

I am running this for loop code and it is creating an error, I cannot find out the problem with it

```
print("""\
This program will prompt you to enter your budget, and amount spent
for a certain month and calculate if your were under or over budget.
You will have the option of choosing how many months you would like to
monitor.\n""")
AmountSpent = 0
Budget = 0
numMonths = int(input("Enter the number of months you would like to monitor:"))
while numMonths<0:
    print("\nNegative value detected!")
    numMonths = int(input("Enter the number of months you would like to monitor"))
for month in range(1, numMonths+1):
    print("\n=====================================")
    AmountBudgeted = float(input("Enter amount budgeted for month "+month+":"))
    while AmountBudgeted<0:
         print("Negative value detected!")
         AmountBudgeted = float(input("Enter amount budgeted for month "+month+":"))
    AmountSpent = float(input("Enter amount spent for month "+month+":"))
    while AmountSpent<0:
         print("Negative value detected!")
         AmountSpent = float(input("Enter amount spent for month "+month+":"))
    if AmountSpent <= AmountBudgeted:
        underBy = AmountBudgeted - AmountSpent
        print("Under budget by " + underBy)
    else:
        overBy = AmountSpent - AmountBudgeted
        print("Over budget by " + overBy)
    if month == "1":
       print(f'your budget is {AmountBudgeted}.')
```

Any ideas on why I am getting this error? I have tried to figure it out on my own but I dont know why it is wrong

Comment: error code is line 14, in <module>
    AmountBudgeted = float(input("Enter amount budgeted for month "+month+":"))
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the for-loop variable `month` is an integer, so you can't concatenate it to a string without converting it first. The easiest way to fix that is to use a format-string instead.

For example, this line:
`AmountBudgeted = float(input("Enter amount budgeted for month "+month+":"))`

Should be changed to:
`float(input(f"Enter amount budgeted for month {month}:"))`

(If you're on an older version of Python you would write `float(input("Enter amount budgeted for month {month}:".format(month=month)))` instead.)

If you're hard-set on using concatenation instead, the trick is to convert `month` to a string first using `str(month)`.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

there is an issue with string and numeric data type. Here is your solution:

```
print("""\
This program will prompt you to enter your budget, and amount spent
for a certain month and calculate if your were under or over budget.
You will have the option of choosing how many months you would like to
monitor.\n""")
AmountSpent = 0
Budget = 0
numMonths = int(input("Enter the number of months you would like to monitor:"))
while numMonths<0:
    print("\nNegative value detected!")
    numMonths = int(input("Enter the number of months you would like to monitor"))
for month in range(1, numMonths+1):
    print("\n=====================================")
    AmountBudgeted = float(input("Enter amount budgeted for month "+str(month)+":"))
    while AmountBudgeted<0:
         print("Negative value detected!")
         AmountBudgeted = float(input("Enter amount budgeted for month "+str(month)+":"))
    AmountSpent = float(input("Enter amount spent for month "+str(month)+":"))
    while AmountSpent<0:
         print("Negative value detected!")
         AmountSpent = float(input("Enter amount spent for month "+str(month)+":"))
    if AmountSpent <= AmountBudgeted:
        underBy = AmountBudgeted - AmountSpent
        print("Under budget by " + str(underBy))
    else:
        overBy = AmountSpent - AmountBudgeted
        print("Over budget by " + str(overBy))
    if month == "1":
       print(f'your budget is {AmountBudgeted}.')
```